# Collection view resizing issue iPhone 4 vs iPhone 5

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection controller inside a view.

The collection controller does not cover 40 px at the top of the screen so that I can put buttons there.

On the iphone 4 it looks like this (proper way):
Blue is the collection view, Red is the cell
[image]

However on the iPhone 5 it looks like this and I am not really sure why it won't spread and cover the blue parts

[image]

The interface builder for this looks like:

Collection view:
[image]

Collection view cell
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: I disable Autoresize Subviews and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Collection View has a fixed size. Do you have AutoLayout enabled? If yes, simply go to the iPhone 5's view and adjust the size so that it fits the iPhone 5 **constraints**. After that it should automatically size to iPhone 5 and iPhone <5

**Constraints**: InterfaceBuilder will do some 'magnetic' behavior if you reach these constraints.

Comment: What do you mean iPhone 5 view?  In IB I have a 3.5 inch view that I am working with do you mean change that to 4 inch? I have found that doing this does not make it backwards compatible with 3.5 inch screen, unless I am missing something. I don't have two separate views, just one that resizes

Comment: And yes, I have use Autolayout checked

Comment: Yes i mean 4 inch screen. Maybe you have AutoLayout not enabled (iOS 6 feature) in this case i think you are required to do this in code. But usually you can snap them to the borders and they will stay at their position regardless the screen size.

Comment: I just tried changing to four, resizing everything to make bigger, and when I launched the iPhone 4 simulator, I get a blank screen and a message saying ||||the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2013-03-23 10:09:06.977 [21916:c07] the item height must be less that the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.

Comment: It sounds like you changed the size of CollectionViews content and not the CollectionView itself

Comment: Ok, yes I resized the content, however if I dont do that, the cell just stays in the middle still...

Comment: Then you may drag the component in 4inch view and it should snap to the top or bottom boundary. Then resize so that it fits all boundaries.

Comment: which component? cell or collection view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26782/discussion-between-waf-and-mr-vvoo)

Comment: @WilliamFalcon did you find a solution, I have a similar issue?

Comment: Use autolayout to fix this. Add Distance from top, add distance from bottom and dont fix the collection view height